# How can send output data using (Gstreamer) from input file (dinesh.ogg) to udpsink ip & port?

Tags: c, gstreamer-1.0

I am following this (Gstreamer) command line. But I want to add element "udpsink" in this command line.

```
gst-launch-1.0  filesrc location=testfile.ogg ! oggdemux name=demuxer demuxer. ! queue ! vorbisdec ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink demuxer. ! queue ! theoradec ! autovideosink
```

So I am trying :

```
gst-launch-1.0  filesrc location=testfile.ogg ! oggdemux name=demuxer demuxer. ! queue ! vorbisdec ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink demuxer. ! queue ! theoradec ! autovideosink ! udpsink host=127.0.0.0 port=22
```

But I am facing the warning in the terminal. :

> WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link autovideosink0 to udpsink0.